# RK4 in 2D gravity simulation probs

Tags: actionscript-3, physics, gravity

In actionscript 3.0, I have two objects (a central red star and a orbiting blue planet). I want to use RK4 to plot the orbit. I'm running the simulation once per frame, and drawing once per frame. I have to relate the position of the blue planet in x,y to the central planet so I may be getting lost in the conversion somewhere. This is just for the 1,1 quadrant.  I will be adjusting the gravity vector as the blue planet crosses from quadrant to quadrant.

PROBLEM: If I alter the time step, the orbit changes drastically.  At small time steps, the orbit becomes a straight line.  At large time steps, the orbit becomes tighter.  The cooefficients for computing the acceleration for each "K" are not being scaled by dt (except for it being passed through the previous velocity vector).

Here is the RK4 code snip:

http://pastebin.com/Ee6HzBQ2

Comment: The blue planet has to have the right initial velocity in order to orbit the red planet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed. You need to have the right speed and have the velocity's direction tangential to the circular orbit if you want a circular orbit.

Comment: My guess is that you inadvertently made your initial velocity dependent on your time step by fixing the spatial step.

Comment: I would like to know why you chose RK4 for your integration method? I have made a 3D gravitational simulation and the best integration method was implicit euler.
I also did explicit euler and verlet. The most difficult thing in the simulation was making sure that the initial velocity was correct. If this is not correct depending on which integration method you are using it will either spiral inward or fly out of orbit. Implicit euler is the best method for gravitational simulations because it cancels out the rounding error by itself.